# How to represent list or arrays in a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have a JSON document like this -

```
{\"pp\": [0, 1024, 4, 1028, 8]}
```

Now how do I represent this `[0, 1024, 4, 1028, 8]` in a shell script?

something like below? does shell script have lists? And then how do I iterate that and print out the result in a shell script?

```
#!/bin/bash

PRIMARY_PARTITION=[0, 1024, 4, 1028, 8]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PRIMARY_PARTITION=(0 1024 4 1028 8)

for el in "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}"; do echo "[$el]"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PRIMARY_PARTITION=(0 1024 4 1028 8)
```

Elements are `${PRIMARY_PARTITION[0]}`, `${PRIMARY_PARTITION[1]}`, etc. The entire array is `"${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}"`.